# How do you fix Visual studio so it can detect errors in code and also show all options in the intellisense?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a game on unity, i have add several game objects and i wanted to make my player move.
so i open up a C# script and started to type down a couple of if statements, though the IntelliSense in Visual Studio isn't showing nearly as much of the options that there should be and it states that there is no issues that have been found

So i decided to type down code that i knew wouldn't work [image of broken code, stating that there are not issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frqtv.png) though once i save it, switched back to unity, unity stateed at the bottom that the code does not work due to the variable not existing (this was the issue that i obsivously wanted visual studio to address though didn't)[Unity stating that the code doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ4o2.png)

Also i was trying to type "if (Input.GetKetDown("Space")) though the IntelliSense didn't show any option for "Input" when i started typing it [The intelliSense when i have typed "In"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1AGX.png)

Comment: Your navigation bar at the top says "Miscellaneous files" which means you're not working within a `.csproj` project. You need a project file to use IDEs properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that you have the Visual Studio Editor module installed in `Window > Package Manager`.
   [image: Visual Studio Editor Package]
2. Check that you have Visual Studio selected as the External Script Editor in `Edit > Preferences...`.
   [image: External Script Editor]
3. Close Visual Studio if it's currently open.
4. Press the `Regenerate project files` button in the same view.
5. Open a script in Visual Studio by double-clicking it in the Project window.

If the issue ever happens again, redoing steps 3 to 5 should fix it.

Comment: while this does work, it seems that every time I load into unity, I have to step 2, do you know a while that would save this setting?

Comment: You could try uninstalling all Visual Studio versions from your computer (including 2019 if you still have that installed) and then reinstall Visual Studio 2022.